# python looping through .dat files to structure unstructured data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read .dat files through a directory which the code below works correctly when working with structured data( e.g. delimited text and/or csv). I am trying to read 3 dat files into pandas and append them together and extract the filename to append it to the last column of the dataframe.

A snippet of the .dat is here, this is just an example I made up to show the data (the first few lines is junk that I want to skip:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
{"Basketball_Player_Name" : "Michael Jordan", "Bulls" : {"school" :[ { 'North Carolina' : {"id":1},
"sneaker_brand" : {'brandOfSneaker" : {'Nike': JustDoIt}, "Championships" :[[ 6]]}, "Statistics" :"bunchofStats", "Address" : "Chicago,IL",     "Export_Data" : "xls", "Version: 2}  and then more junk
```

I want to be to extract the following as column headers into a pandas df:
Basketball_Player_Name
Statistics
Address
Export Data

Then store the data that is associated in the correct column
Michael Jordan,
bunchOfStats,
Chicago,IL,
xls

I would appreciate any assistance, thank you!

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

### read through a directory
path =r'C:\Users\d\Desktop\data' # use your path
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.dat")

#create the dataframe
frame = pd.DataFrame()

#append all the data to an empty list and read the files
list_total = []
 for file_ in allFiles:
  df = pd.read_csv(file_ , delim_whitespace = True)
  df['filename'] = os.path.basename(file_)
  list_total.append(df)


frame = pd.concat(list_total)

#Name the columns with a dictionary with the column info you want to store
frame.columns = ['names','stats','address','data_format']


#Print the frame
print(frame)

#saves data back to csv
frame.to_csv('C:/Users/d/Desktop/data/output.csv')
```

Comment: But this is JSON, not CSV.

Comment: see I wasn't sure of the data structure, how could I accomplish the structuring if its a JSON?

Comment: [`pd.read_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html)?

Comment: regular read_json doesnt work, I am getting the JSONDecodeerror message

Comment: this is a json embedded into a .dat file that I am trying to parse into a pandas dataframe